# Protobuf ByteString to String in java

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I tried to convert Protobuf ByteString to java String but getting this as result.

```
<ByteString@4cd1c1f6 size=11 contents="\b\350\210\206\226\201\302\3658\020\005">
```

It is supposed to be string with date and time.

Inside *.proto file DateTime field looks like this:

```
bytes DateTime = 2;
```

I tried string DateTime, but then I get "Protocol message had invalid UTF-8." exception.

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried .toStringUtf8()  ?

Comment: "It is supposed be string with date and time." - what do you mean by that? Who defined the proto, and what do *they* say about it? (If it's meant to be a string, why have they declared it as bytes?)

Comment: First thanks for answers. Yes, I tried .toStringUtf8() but then I get ������8 :) . I have C# class that is used to work with this proto object and now I need that service rewriten in JAVA. So everything works except strings :) .

Comment: Then it sounds like this probably isn't a string. (Which makes sense, given that it's meant to be binary data...) If you could show what you did in C#, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Here is class in C# that works https://gist.github.com/MrDexterX/9eac3187ee21bd836e0bfd0a0df3f726 . Thank you for your time.